# Jumping bug on Maximize on Play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently having trouble with my jumping, everything works fine when my game window is small but when put my game window to maximize on Display + build it then my Jumping mechanics got trouble, instead of jumping the right amount that I told it to do, it just jumps up a tiny bit and got pulled right back down. Currently, I'm using the update method for it and here is the code:

```
   void CalculateMovement()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        _playerAnim.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalInput));

        if (_controller.isGrounded == true)
        {
           
           
            _playerAnim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            _canDoubleJump = false;
            _canWallJump = false;
            _direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, 0);
            _velocity = _direction * _speed;
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _canWallJump == false && _canDoubleJump == false)
            {
                _playerAudio.clip = _playerSoundsClip[5];
                _playerAudio.Play();
                _playerAnim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
                Instantiate(_dustSmoke, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.5f, transform.position.z),Quaternion.identity);
                _canDoubleJump = true;
                _yVelocity = _jumpHeight;
               
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
            if (_canWallJump == false && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)  && _canDoubleJump == true)
            {
                _yVelocity = 0;
                _playerAudio.clip = _playerSoundsClip[5];
                _playerAudio.Play();
                _playerAnim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
                Instantiate(_dustSmoke, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.5f, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
                 _yVelocity = _jumpHeight * _bonusJumpMultiplier;
                 _canDoubleJump = false;
                


            }
            else if (_canWallJump == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) )
            {
                _yVelocity = 0;
                _yVelocity = _jumpHeight;
                _velocity = _wallSurfaceNormal * _speed  * pushPower;
                _playerAudio.clip = _playerSoundsClip[7];
                _playerAudio.Play();
               
                Instantiate(_dustSmoke, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.5f, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
                _canWallJump = false;

                SwitchRotation();




            }


            _yVelocity -= _gravity;
        }

        _velocity.y = _yVelocity;

        _controller.Move(_velocity*Time.deltaTime );
    }
```

I tried to use the `Debug.log(_yVelocity.ToString())` but the number seems normal and I also tried to hard coding numbers in to my movement method but still, it still got the same bug so anyone knows how to fix this.

edit: after messing around with this, I found out that the problem COULD be related to my `_yVelocity = _gravity`since when change it, my character jumps super height on small display but he jumps normal on "Maximize on Display".

Comment: Do you have any relation to a UI element, Window size ? Is `_gravity` or `_jumpHeight` float variable, do you set them by code?

Comment: no, not at all, they dont have any relation to UI element and for _gravity and _jumpHeight, I put them as private and [Serialize] to modify them in the inspector and did not modify them anymore

Comment: Do you have editor code using `#if UNITY_EDITOR` ? By the way if you are using a character controller you should probably use your logic on FixedUpdate insteed of Update. Maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why this was happening, turns out everything was because of frame rates so I was able to fix this by just receive Inputs from void Update() and apply it in void FixedUpdate;